# vb.net - how do i fix crossthreading with background worker

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

In VB.Net I've created a background worker which seems to work. It is set up like this:

```
Private bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker

Public Sub construct_configure()
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
        AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted
end sub
```

Then I have the doWork Sub set up like this:

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

        ' create the picture box
        pic_holder = New PictureBox()

        ' Show GIF and disable whatever you need to
        With pic_holder
            .Image = My.Resources.counter_gif
            .Size = New Size(200, 100)
            .Location = New Point(0, 0)
            .Visible = True
            .BackColor = Color.Red

        End With
        Main.Controls.Add(pic_holder)
        pic_holder.BringToFront()

        MessageBox.Show("worker started")

    End Sub
```

The message box shows up when I click on my button to call the Sub, but the animated gif never does. I'm trying to simply set up an indicator that there is some background work going on. The gif shows up when I set it up in the parent sub.

Also, I'd like to place the gif in a panel that already exists, but every time I try to, I get a cross threading error that says the panel was created in another thread. How can I get around that?

Thanks.

Comment: is this a windows application or WCF?  WCF has a way to easily invoke methods from a GUI control's thread using Dispatcher... The approaches available depend on your app's technology.

Comment: You fix it by not using a BGW.  There's completely no point in using one when code takes microseconds.

Comment: @HansPassant why are you assuming the code only takes microseconds?  The actual work might take quite a long time.  I'm assuming the OP left out what actual background work was going to be accomplished either because it hasn't been coded just yet or because it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: It is irrelevant if he does anything else.  The code that causes the crash does not require a BGW.

Comment: It is a Windows Forms Application. Hans, What's going on in the other thread is completely irrelevant to the question. VB provides a background worker thread and I'm trying to utilize it. If the reason for wanting to use it is not important enough for you to warrant your help, then so be it. There are others her who are not so judgmental. For those that care, the background process is going to a web site to retrieve some information. While my program waits for a response from the site the UI is frozen. I want the user to know they are waiting for a response and the program is still working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended that if you want to invoke the main form you should do this in the *ProgressChanged* event. The bw_ProgressChanged is called on the same thread as the main form.

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork

    'WORKER THREAD, do not invoke main form.

    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)

    'Report start
    worker.ReportProgress(0)

    'Do some work...
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

    'Report end.
    worker.ReportProgress(100)

End Sub

Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bw.ProgressChanged

    'MAIN THREAD, safe to invoke main form.

    If (e.ProgressPercentage = 0) Then
        'Started: Do something...
    ElseIf (e.ProgressPercentage = 100) Then
        'Stopped: Do something...
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, While I can now call the other existing panel without error from the progressChanged Sub, my picture box still does not show up. I put a message box in the progressChanged Sub and I see the message box, but still nothing on the IU.

Comment: OK, I've made a little progress. I put the creation of the picture box in the ProgressChanged Sub and now it does show up but not until AFTER the background worker has completed. So it just sits there and waits for the worker to complete, then it shows up. I have nothing in the RunWorkerCompletedSub.

Comment: Try change `Main.Controls.Add(pic_holder)` to `Me.Controls.Add(pic_holder)` if you're adding it to the form. If not, then i need to see the code for _bw_ProgressChanged_.

Comment: What you should do is to create the control _before_ calling `Me.bw.RunWorkerAsync()`, and then remove it in the _RunWorkerCompleded_ event. PS: Always check the state of the worker before running async. `Me.bw.IsBusy = False`

Comment: OK, I finally got it! Thanks a lot Bjorn! What I had to do was reverse the process. I was using the main program to call the web site and wait for a response and trying to use the background worker to show the animated gif while I waited, but what I really needed to do was send the process of calling the web site and waiting for a response to the background worker letting my main program stay responsive. So after doing that, I was able to figure it out using your suggestion above.